# OpenCV compile error Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so /lib/libbz2.so.1: could not read symbols: File in wrong format

Tags: opencv, cmake

I'm trying to install OpenCV-2.4.9 on my CentOS 6.4. machine.
I downloaded the source in ~/Downloads/opencv-2.4.9.
from there, I did 'mkdir build; cd build'. Then did

`cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D WITH_TBB=ON -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D WITH_QT=ON -D WITH_OPENGL=ON --enable-shared ..`

and did 'make -j2'.
Below is the message I got  (this is result of re-running using just 'make')

```
[  3%] Built target libtiff
[  4%] Built target opencv_core_pch_dephelp
[  4%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_core
[  6%] Built target opencv_core
[  6%] Built target opencv_ts_pch_dephelp
[  6%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_ts
[  6%] Built target opencv_imgproc_pch_dephelp
[  7%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_imgproc
[ 11%] Built target opencv_imgproc
[ 11%] Built target opencv_flann_pch_dephelp
[ 11%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_flann
[ 12%] Built target opencv_flann
[ 12%] Built target opencv_highgui_pch_dephelp
[ 12%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_highgui
Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so
/lib/libbz2.so.1: could not read symbols: File in wrong format
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.9] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I did some search, but no good answers. Can anybody give me a hint on what's wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem and my solution is remove all build file (or CMakeCache.txt) and cmake again.

The problem is that cmake finds a 32-bit library rather than the 64-bit one, which should be found in /lib64/libbz2.so or /usr/lib64/libbz2.so.
Sometimes the cmake get messed up and keep using the cached variable. So if you remove the cache and cmake again, it should find the correct library.

Comment: Weipeng, thanks. After my post, I noticed this lib64 and lib problem, and had passed that libbz2 problem (by changing the $LD_LIBRARY_PATH so that /usr/lib64 comes before /usr/lib). After some days when I try this problem yesterday, I met with another problem. New captuer is here : https://www.flickr.com/photos/129456552@N07/15702597050/

Comment: Modifying `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` did not work for me, but `sed -i 's#/lib/libbz2.so.1#/lib64/libbz2.so.1#g' CMakeCache.txt` did the trick for me.

Comment: @w177us your solution also worked for me on Fedora 21. Thanks!

Comment: @w177us your solution with sed worked for me also on centos 7. Thanks!